# Cancel Observable subscription and wait for Observer to finish

Tags: system.reactive

Is there a better way to write the code below to achieve what stated in the post subject?

I find the following code too complex and too chatty with the use of the extra `Subject<long>`, and not easy to create a generic solution unless you hard code it in each observable.

```cs
var subject = new Subject<long>();
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
var disposable = observable.Do(l => {
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start {l}-{DateTime.Now}");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Console.WriteLine($"Stop {l}-{DateTime.Now}");
        subject.OnNext(l);
    }
}).Subscribe();
cts.Token.Register(disposable.Dispose);

Thread.Sleep(5000);
subject.Subscribe();
cts.Cancel();
subject.FirstAsync().Wait();

Console.WriteLine("Finish");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off writing your code using a `Subject<Unit>` to signal completion. Using an array of `bool` is a bit messy and could cause you grief using that kind of technique in multi-threaded code.

Try this:

```
var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
Subject<Unit> finish = new Subject<Unit>();
observable
    .TakeUntil(finish)
    .Do(l =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Start {l}-{DateTime.Now}");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine($"Stop {l}-{DateTime.Now}");
    })
    .Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finally"))
    .Subscribe(
        l => Console.WriteLine("OnNext"),
        () => Console.WriteLine("Complete"));

Thread.Sleep(5000);
finish.OnNext(Unit.Default);
Console.ReadLine();
```

It produces:

```
Start 0-2017/08/15 13:37:03
Stop 0-2017/08/15 13:37:05
OnNext
Start 1-2017/08/15 13:37:05
Stop 1-2017/08/15 13:37:07
OnNext
Complete
Finally
```

Comment: I totally agreed, i already discover it my self but you deserve the upvote

Answer (score 0):

Actually canceling the subscription results in no further signaling. The correct thing to do is to wait for completion. The subscription auto-dispose after completion so no further handling is required

```
        var observable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
        bool[] finish = {false};
        observable.TakeWhile(l => !finish[0]).Do(l => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Start {l}-{DateTime.Now}");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine($"Stop {l}-{DateTime.Now}");

        }).Finally(() => Console.WriteLine("Finally")).Subscribe(l => {
            Console.WriteLine("OnNext");
        },() => Console.WriteLine("Complete") );
        finish[0] = true;
        Console.ReadKey(true);
```

The above produce the same output without the extra subject